# When using the mvn allure:report command, it throws a javax.inject.Provider error?

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, automated-tests, testng

When creating a report on passed autotests, I encounter an error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-maven-plugin:2.6:report (default-cli) on project adaptationproject: An error has occurred in Allure report generation.: Could not generate the report: InvocationTargetException : javax/inject/Provider: javax.inject.Provider

As I understand it, the error is due to the fact that the dependencies do not fit together, I tried everything, but the report still cannot be done, it always gives javax.inject.Provider

And I had to use the allure version not from qameta, but from Yandex, and after that the problems started.

Here is my pom file:

```
`    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd"><modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
```

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>adaptationproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.7</aspectj.version>
    <typesafe.version>1.4.1</typesafe.version>
    <selenium.version>4.9.0</selenium.version>
    <testng.version>7.7.1</testng.version>
    <common-io.version>2.11.0</common-io.version>
    <common-lang3>3.1</common-lang3>
    <surefire.version>2.20</surefire.version>
    <gson.version>2.2.2</gson.version>
    <maven-compiler.verion>3.8.1</maven-compiler.verion>
    <unirest.version>3.11.12</unirest.version>
    <json.version>20230227</json.version>
    <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
    <logging.version>2.14.1</logging.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.6.0</postgresql.version>
    <celebrium.version>0.0.8</celebrium.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.8.22</kotlin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.7</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${common-io.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
        <artifactId>config</artifactId>
        <version>${typesafe.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>${unirest.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logging.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.celebrium</groupId>
        <artifactId>celebrium-web</artifactId>
        <version>${celebrium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    --add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirs>
                            <sourceDir>src/test/java</sourceDir>
                        </sourceDirs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>analyze</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>libs-release</id>
        <name>libs-release</name>
        <url>http://172.19.202.69/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

</project>`
```

I tried different versions of dependencies, added maven inject, rebuilt the project, etc., but nothing helped, when I enter mvn allure:report, the same error is displayed, but I would like a report to be generated